# Codeigniter 3 application bug: clicking the browser's back button fires signout() function

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I have made a **Registration and login** application in Codeigniter 3. I have been struggling with this bug: after login the user is redirected to the home page *but* clicking the browser's back button fires signout() function, instead of *redirecting* from the Signin page to the home page.

The **Signin controller** has the following code:

```
class Signin extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('signin');
  }

  public function signin()
  {  
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
      $email = $this->input->post('email');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');
      $this->load->model('Usermodel');
      $current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);
      // Unset the current user's data
      if ($current_user) {
       $this->session->set_userdata(
         array(
          'user_id' => $current_user->id,
          'user_email' => $current_user->email,
          'user_first_name' => $current_user->fname,
          'is_logged_in' => TRUE
          )
         );
       redirect('home');  
     } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Incorrect email or password");
        redirect('signin'); 
      }
    }
    else
    {
     $this->load->view('signin');
   }
  }

  public function signout(){
    // Unset the current user's data
    $this->session->unset_userdata('user_id');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('user_email');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('user_first_name');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('is_logged_in');

    // Load the signin view
    $this->load->view('signin'); 
  }
}
```

In the navigation bar (header.php view), I use `is_logged_in` to display the *Sigin*, *Register* and *Signout* buttons when required:

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <?php if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) : ?>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Welcome, <?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_first_name'); ?>
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> My contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></span> All contacts</a></li>
          <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Signin/signout'); ?>" title="Signout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Signout</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <?php else: ?>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Signin</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Register</a></li>
      <?php endif;?>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

After the *Signout* button is used once, and the user *signs in* again, clicking the browser's back button loads `http://localhost/ciauth/index.php/Signin/signout` and fires signout() function.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add mentioned below lines on the top of `index` & `signin` methods.

```
if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')==TRUE)
    redirect('home');
```

Comment: Where _exactly_ in the code? Can you copy my code and add _yours_ to it? Thank you!

Comment: public function index()
  {
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')==TRUE) 
           redirect('home');
    $this->load->view('signin');
  }

public function signin()
  {  
    if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')==TRUE) 
           redirect('home');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');

Comment: I have added `if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')==TRUE) redirect('home');` in the index & signin methods. It only works until I use the _Signout_ button once.

Comment: i think you requirement was "user should redirected to home page on click of browser back button", am i right?

Comment: <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <?php $ci =& get_instance(); if($ci->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) : ?>

Comment: change your php script of header.php for hide or show menu buttons

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs here:

```
$current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);

if($current_user)
{
  #is always !$current_user because $email and $password is empty. you should build condition with userdata first. if userdata not false or whatever condition comparing..and then, how you you pass output(return) in model $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password)??
}
else
{
  #so it going here.
  redirect('signin');
}
```

UPDATE with with new suggestion..

```
public function signin() {  
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
   $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');

   if ($this->form_validation->run()) { // that's mean user come here after submit form..
      $email = $this->input->post('email');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');
      $this->load->model('Usermodel');
      $current_user = $this->Usermodel->user_login($email, $password);

      if ($current_user) { #maksure you function user_login() in Usermodel will not return FALSE if success login with $email and #password (must return something or TRUE). Then MUST return FALSE if failed to login.
         // re-set back the current user's data
         $this->session->set_userdata(
            array(
               'user_id' => $current_user->id,
               'user_email' => $current_user->email,
               'user_first_name' => $current_user->fname,
               'is_logged_in' => TRUE
            )
         );
         redirect('home'); 

      } else {

         $this->session->set_flashdata("signin_failure", "Incorrect email or password");
         redirect('signin'); 

      }
   } else { // user come here not after submit login form. possible click browsers button..

      $user_id = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
      if($user_id){ // if return TRUE user already login..
         print_r('hello ' . $this->session->userdata('user_first_name') . ', youre already login.. do something below');
         #do something..
      } else {
         #you need to sign in with this form because you're not login.
         $this->load->view('signin');
      }

   }

} // end of function..
```

Comment: I do have this: `$this->session->set_userdata(
         array(
          'user_id' => $current_user->id,
          'user_email' => $current_user->email,
          'user_first_name' => $current_user->fname,
          'is_logged_in' => TRUE
          )
         );` Is there a way I can use it? Can you give a sample code? Thank you!